# R implement group generics Ops() to enable comparison of S3 objects

Tags: r, oop, generics, comparison

I am creating an S3 class in R for which I would like to be able to do comparisons like `"<"`, `">"`, and `"=="`. Rather than implement each of these separately from what I've read about [group generics](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/groupGeneric.html) I believe I can do so using `Ops()` but I haven't found any good examples of how to do this.

Suffice it to say that for `myClass` I can create an `as.integer.myClass()` function, and that to compare `a` and `b` I could just convert to integer first:

```
if(as.integer(a) < as.integer(b)) foo
```

This totally works, but I would so much rather write

```
if(a < b) foo
```

I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
Ops.myClass <- function(e1, e2) {
  Ops(as.integer(e1), as.integer(e2))
}
```

> ```
> a < b
> ```
>
> ```
> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
>  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘Ops’ for signature ‘"integer", "integer"’
> ```

Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `Ops(my, my)` fails with the same error -- you're not invoking `Ops`, but a generic that is a member of the Ops group. So get the generic and invoke it on the transformed types

```
Ops.my = function(e1, e2) get(.Generic)(as.integer(e1), as.integer(e2))
```

with

```
> my1 = structure(1:5, class="my")
> my2 = structure(5:1, class="my")
> my1 > my2
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> my1 == my2
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! Based on your answer, I made a longer answer (to my own question) also for other groups here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978228/4640346

Answer (score 2):

The general approach I have for this is to use `.Generic` and switch on the method.

```
Ops.myClass <- function(e1, e2)
{
  op = .Generic[[1]]
  switch(op,
         `<` = {
           print("called less than function")
           as.integer(e1) < as.integer(e2)
         },
         `>` = {
            print("called greater than function")
            as.integer(e1) > as.integer(e2)
         },
         stop("undefined operation")
  )
}

a <- 1
b <- 3
class(a) <- "myClass"
class(b) <- "myClass"


a > b
[1] "called greater than function"
[1] FALSE
a < b
[1] "called less than function"
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This works, but I was trying to avoid implementing each comparison separately.

Comment: @BrianStamper that's fine, this is just how you could approach it if you can't assume each method would be handled correctly.