# Own class build on top of integer or numeric and getting the propagation to higher and lower classes right

Tags: r

I stumbled about a propagation issue of an `integer` to the higher type `numeric` and back in conjunction with my own class `myclass` on top of it:

```
x <- c(1L, 2L, 3L)
class(x) # integer

y <- x
class(y) <- c("myclass", class(y))
class(y) # c("myclass", "integer")

x2 <- x / 10
class(x2) # numeric - propagated to higher class numeric

y2 <- y / 10
class(y2) # c("myclass", "integer") - not propagated to c("myclass", "numeric")
y2 # 0.1 0.2 0.3 - but decimal numbers!

y3 <- y2
class(y3) <- setdiff(class(y3), "myclass")
class(y3) # integer
y3 # 0 0 0 - integers
```

I am looking for a way to either get the up propagation to `c("myclass", "numeric")` if the operation does yield such results or for a way to keep the decimals when getting rid of the "myclass" part (or both). I do not want to define my own operations for `"myclass"` but rather rely on the dispatching to the basic classes.

I know I can use `typeof()` to distinguish between the internal storage and then check for it before removing `"myclass"` `by class<-` and setting class to `"numeric"` (or use `attr(obj, "class") <- NULL` to have it done for me as the class is determined then). But still, how do I get `c("myclass", "numeric")` when I perform operations that yield doubles?

Comment: Just set the class to `myclass`:`class(x)<-"myclass"`. You don't need to set the class for a storage type; just let R deal with it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I really want to keep the original class as well. `myclass` shall serve as an extention to various classes, e.g. numerics, logicals, factors.

Comment: Beware that `numeric`, `logical`, `integer`, `character` and `list`  are not classes as the others. They don't have a `class` attribute; rather it's their storage type that determines the class. You can always determine what an object is through the usual `is.xxx` functions, so you don't need basically ever to have a place which says what the object is.

Comment: Yes, it would just be great if the class attribute is set when the basic class is determined from the storage mode in cases with length(attr(object, class)) > 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using groupGenerics for class `"myclass"`: one does not need to define own operations for each and every single operation (+, -, /, log, ...) for "myclass" but can rely on groups of operations (Ops, Math, Complex, Summary), see `?groupGeneric`.

Here I show by an example how to use a groupGeneric for the groups Ops, Math, and Complex (analogously for group Summary, but I did not need it). The example just takes away the class "myclass" wrapped around the basic classes and re-adds it again once an operation from one of the three groups is invoked on an object of class `"myclass"`. Sure, one can easily do more stuff in the defined groupGenerics, but this is just to illustrate. `get(.Generic)(x)` is a crucial point here: it fetches the generic for the operation invoked for for the basic class and applies it to object `x`.

```
Math.myclass <- function(x, ...) {
#  print("Math.myclass executed!") # debug output

  if (inherits(x, "myclass")) class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "myclass")

  x <- get(.Generic)(x, ...)
  ## do more stuff here ##
  class(x) <- union("myclass", class(x))
  return(x)
}

Complex.myclass <- function(z) {
#  print("Complex.myclass executed!") # debug output

  if (inherits(z, "myclass")) class(z) <- setdiff(class(z), "myclass")

  z <- get(.Generic)(z)
  ## do more stuff here ##
  class(z) <- union("myclass", class(z))
  return(z)
}

Ops.myclass <- function(e1, e2) {
# Ops can have 1 or 2 arguments
#  print("Ops.myclass executed!") # debug output

  miss_e2 <- missing(e2)

  # either one or both could be class "myclass"
  if (inherits(e1, "myclass")) class(e1) <- setdiff(class(e1), "myclass")
  if (!miss_e2 && inherits(e2, "myclass")) class(e2) <- setdiff(class(e2), "myclass")

  res <- if (!miss_e2) {
            get(.Generic)(e1, e2)
          } else {
            get(.Generic)(e1)
          }
  ## do more stuff here ##
  class(res) <- union("myclass", class(res))
  return(res)
}
```

Comment: This post was helpful in finding the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35903266/4640346